# Divide all columns by another column. Also divide all columns by aggregate function(min, max, sum, count, etc.)

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm guessing this is not possible without defining a function. The idea is that you have a table like

table:

```
----------------
| A | B | Total|
|---|---|------|
| 1 | 2 |  3   |
| 4 | 5 |  9   |
| 6 | 7 | 13   |
----------------

select */Total from table

----------------------------
|   A   |   B   |   Total  |
|-------|-------|----------|
| 0.333 | 0.667 |  1.00    |
| 0.8   | 0.556 |  1.00    |
| 0.462 | 0.538 |  1.00    |
----------------------------

select */(select max(*) from table) from table

----------------------------
|   A   |   B   |   Total  |
|-------|-------|----------|
| 0.167 | 0.286 |  0.231   |
| 0.667 | 0.714 |  0.692   |
| 1.000 | 1.000 |  1.000   |
----------------------------
```

Comment: What would be the expected output as per your sample data ?

Comment: Can't really understand the result you want.

Comment: Duh. I meant to do that.

Comment: What is `max(*)` ???  What is `*/Total` ???  These are not valid SQL expressions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know! If they were, then I would have my answer. Those are placeholders for an SQL expression that would work.

Comment: Thanks for not downvoting me while I edited my question!

Comment: Why? How long does it take to type in all the column names?

Comment: @SalmanA I have a study with 134 samples. I could generate the SQL text string, which is what I'm doing. But wondering if there is an SQL trick.

Comment: @albater Its simply a bad design. They probably did not create a "divide all" operator to discourage table designs that grow column wise instead of rows.

Comment: @SalmanA it wouldn't grow at all, as you can see in my examples. I'm wondering if there is an SQL equivalent to something like this in R: `df = apply(df, 2, function(col){col/max(col)})`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want operators on your output. You can simply do this to get your first example:

```
SELECT A/total, B/total, (A+B)/total FROM `table`
```

You don't even need a 'total' column:

```
SELECT A/(A+B), B/(A+B), 1 as total FROM `table`
```

Second one, if you are trying to get the average, same logic applies.